# use "geth attach" command but failed in ubuntu

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, ethereum

i opened a shell and creat a new account and use "miner.start()"
 than i opened a new shell and use "geth attach" command but failed，
and the error message is

```
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /home/hzxscyq/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory
```

then i try "geth" and the error message is

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use
```

i want to know how to use geth attach?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **geth.ipc** gets created when Geth is succesfully launched.It looks like
another Geth instance is already running,which could be stopping the succesful launch.Find that Geth process and kill it.

```
ps -eaux | grep "geth"
```

Get the process id and kill that process using

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Now invoke geth and attach to it